# Using other languages with Pylatex

Tags: python, latex

I'm trying to get hebrew to pring into a pdf using pylatex.  In a sample hebrew .tex file that I'm trying to emulate the format of, the header looks like this:

```
%\title{Hebrew document in WriteLatex - מסמך בעברית}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
```

I was able to emulate this entire header except for the line `\selectlanguage{hebrew}`.  I'm not sure how I should go about getting this in my .tex file using pylatex.  The code for generating the rest of the file is:

```
doc = pylatex.Document('basic', inputenc = 'utf8x', lmodern = False, fontenc = None, textcomp = None)

    packages = [Package('babel', options = ['english', 'hebrew']), Package('inputenc', options = 'utf8enc')]
    doc.packages.append(Package('babel', options = ['english', 'hebrew']))

    doc.append(text.decode('utf-8'))
    doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False, compiler = "XeLaTeX ")
    doc.generate_tex()
```

And the header of the .tex file generated is:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}%
```

How do you get the `selectlanguage` line there?  I'm pretty new to latex so I apologize for not being so accurate with my terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`Command`](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/pylatex/pylatex.base_classes.command.html#pylatex.base_classes.command.Command):

```
from pylatex import Command
```

To add it to your preamble,

```
doc.preamble.append(Command('selectlanguage', 'hebrew'))
```

or to another specific place in your document,

```
doc.append(Command('selectlanguage', 'hebrew'))
```